# Error message: No virtual network in this subscription - when Trying to add a peering

Tags: azure-networking, virtual-network

For some reason, I am not able to select any virtual network when Adding Peering. E.g., I am trying to add a peering between vnet0 and Vnet 1, but when trying to select virtual network. There is a message " No virtual network in this subscription". Is this related to the subscription type? I have free Azure student subscription.

Thanks[AZ vnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoSPN.jpg)
[AZ Vnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoSPN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your page in the portal. I had the same issue.
The CLI essentially proves to be faster when updating in Azure.